# Backup / Mirror a drive to JBOD storage pool

Tags: nas, windows-server, storage-spaces

I have a home NAS server running Windows Server 2016 with a JBOD of 5 disks configured in a single Storage Pool. I recently bought a single drive which is approximately the same size as the entire pool.

I'm looking for a way to use the pool and the new drive in "RAID 1" together, or something similar to RAID 5 (considering all drives) - meaning I need the NAS to be able to tolerate a single drive failure.

I'd prefer a solution where I don't have to remove all data from the existing drives.
I've been thinking about just running a nightly script that backs up the pool into the new drive - is this a good enough method?

Would like to hear any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RAID 10?

Personally I would copy everything off JBOD and junk those drives. Then buy another drive to backup to as well. Unless you don't care about your data, but then there's no point in RAID.
Hard drives are cheap. Data loss may not be.

Comment: using RAID 10 is out of the question since the smallest drive is 500GB, making it irrelevant. 
If I could just buy another drive, I'd do that. I'm looking for a solution for what I have right now until I could actually get another drive.

Comment: I'm not sure what effect drive size has on the "relevance" of a disk array. Or quite the purpose of striping between jbod and one physical disk. Guess I'm a bit confused about what you want to achieve and why you said RAID. LVM (logical volume management) may be the solution you're after. Works in *nix, but it's going to be google-fu for you if you want it in windows.